# How to programmatically reindex product after update ex. price/stock quantity

Tags: configurable-product, api, reindex, swagger

how to programmatically reindex product after update ex. price/stock quantity using Magento ver. 2.3.2 API via Swagger? I do application in C# which sync my system with Magento. I have a lot of article, so I think migrate ex. Pirce using catalogBasePriceStorage. But after that, i must manually reindex from admin panel.
s there any way to execute reindex from Magento Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom Rest API in magento 2 and use below code with magento

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
  $indexerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
$indexerIds = array(
    'catalog_category_product',
    'catalog_product_category',
    'catalog_product_price',
    'catalog_product_attribute',
    'cataloginventory_stock',
    'catalogrule_product',
    'catalogsearch_fulltext',
);
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
    $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
    $indexer->load($indexerId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$indexerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
$indexerIds = array(
    'catalog_category_product',
    'catalog_product_category',
    'catalog_product_price',
    'catalog_product_attribute',
    'cataloginventory_stock',
    'catalogrule_product',
    'catalogsearch_fulltext',
);
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
    $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
    $indexer->load($indexerIds);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
```